# Change vertical axis starting point

Tags: reporting-services

How do I change the horizontal ( X) axis starting point from 0 to 50. I would like a result like this:

[image]

Besides moving the X axis 0 starting point to 50 then I would also like to have only two major gridlines - one at 70 and one at 30.

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to set the CrossAt property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need are striplines rather than moving the axes.

This will work for both horizontal and vertical lines, you can hide major tick marks once you have the lines in the right position.

Here I show how to add the horizontal line at position 50.

Click the Y-Axis in the designer, then hit F4 to view properties.

Look for the 'StripLines' property. and click the `...`

Add a new stripline and set the followi9ng properties (I used 15 in my example so change this to 50), set the other formatting properties as you like. The 5 properties highlighted are the main ones you need to look at.

[image]

Here' the output from my sample chart.

[image]

Repeat for X-Axis and you should be there.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question Alan. I found that I need to set the CrossAt property.